# splitting input line with varying formats in tcl with

Tags: tcl

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to write a tcl script which given the input file

```
input               hreadyin;
input  wire         htrans;       
input  wire [7:0]   haddr;   
output logic [31:0] hrdata;
output              hreadyout;
```

will produce

```
hreadyin(hreadyin),
htrans(htrans),
haddr(haddr[7:0]),
hrdata(hrdata[31:0]),
hready(hreadyout)
```

In other words, the format is:

`<input/output> <wire/logic optional> <width, optional> <paramName>;`

with the number of whitespaces unrestricted between each of them.

I have no problem reading from the input file and was able to put each line in a `$line` element. Now I have been trying things like:

```
  set param0 [split $line "input"]
  set param1 [lindex $param0 1]
```

But since not all lines have "`input"` line in them i am unable to get the elements i want (the name and the width if it exists).

Is there another command in tcl capable for doing this kind of parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp command is useful to find words separated by arbitrary whitespace:

```
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    # get all whitespace-separated words in the line, ignoring the semi-colon
    set i [string first ";" $line]
    set fields [regexp -inline -all {\S+} [string range $line 0 $i-1]]

    switch -exact -- [llength $fields] {
        2 - 3 {
            set name [lindex $fields end]
            puts [format "%s(%s)," $name $name]
        }
        4 {
            lassign $fields - - width name
            puts [format "%s(%s%s)," $name $name $width]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at something like

```
# Compress all multiple spaces to single spaces

set compressedLine [resgub " +" $line " "]

set items [split [string range $compressedLine 0 end-1] $compressedLine " "]
switch [llength $items] {
    2 {
        # Handle case where neither wire/logic nor width is specificed

        set inputOutput [lindex $items 0]
        set paramName [lindex $items 1]
        .
        .
        .
    }

    4 {
        # Handle case where both wire/logic and width are specified

        set inputOutput [lindex $items 0]
        set wireLogic [lindex $items 1]
        set width [lindex $items 2]
        set paramName [lindex $items 3]
        .
        .
        .
    }

    default {
        # Don't know how to handle other cases - add them in if you know
        puts stderr "Can't handle $line
    }
}
```

I hope it's not legal to have exactly one of wire/logic and width specified - you'd need to work hard to determine which is which.

(Note the `[string range...]` fiddle to discard the semicolon at the end of the line)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you can write up a regex that catches the right data, you can do this with this:

```
set data [open "file.txt" r]
set output [open "output.txt" w]

while {[gets $data line] != -1} {
    regexp -- {(\[\d+:\d+\])?\s*(\w+);} $line - width params
    puts $output "$params\($params$width\),"
}

close $data
close $output
```

This one will also print the comma you have inserted in your expected output, but will insert it in the last line as well so you get:

```
hreadyin(hreadyin),
htrans(htrans),
haddr(haddr[7:0]),
hrdata(hrdata[31:0]),
hready(hreadyout),
```

If you don't want it and the file is not too large (apparently the limit is 2147483672 bytes for a list, which I'm gonna use), you could use a group like this:

```
set data [open "file.txt" r]
set output [open "output.txt" w]

set listing "" #Empty list

while {[gets $data line] != -1} {
    regexp -- {(\[\d+:\d+\])?\s*(\w+);} $line - width params
    lappend listing "$params\($params$width\)" #Appending to list instead
}

puts $output [join $listing ",\n"] #Join all in a single go

close $data
close $output
```

Comment: It's just another way in using regex to skip checking steps.

Comment: Easiest solution, but `-all` isn't necessary and `info exists width` will always be true after the first line. `regexp` never unsets submatchvars.

Comment: @potrzebie huh, I was under the impression it doesn't even create the variable (or unsets it with no matches). Edited the code, since it's redundant with that. Thank you :)

Comment: If the overall regexp matches, *all* submatchvars are set (creating them if they don't exist). If the regexp doesn't match, no variables are touched.